# How making and verifying a signature with PGP using command line

Tags: public-key-encryption, pgp

I could not find any good example of signing and verifying a file using PGP, I hope the following example could be useful.
I will use Bob and Alice to explain it.

**1**.Bob install Alice’s PGP Public key in his machine:

**$ gpg --import <Key_Alice>-pub-sub.asc**

**2**.Alice signs and encrypts a document (TestMessage.txt) using her PGP Private key :

**$ gpg --output TestMessageSignedByAlice.txt  -a  --sign ./TestMessage.txt**

--output : write output to FILE (TestMessageSignedByAlice.txt)

-a, --armor :output file should be in ascii format

--sign : document to sign  and encrypt (TestMessage.txt)

The result is a document signed and encrypted (TestMessageSignedByAlice.txt) by Alice using her PGP private key.

**3**.Finally  Bob verifies Alice’s signed  document and decrypts document using Alice’s PGP Public Key. The original document content will be found in document TestMessageDecrypt.txt .

**$ gpg --output TestMessageDecrypt.txt  --decrypt ./TestMessageSignedByAlice.txt**

--decrypt:  file to verify signature and to decrypt (TestMessageSignedByAlice.txt)

--output : write output to FILE (TestMessageDecrypt.txt)

I used documentation from :
https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I did update the explanation giving more detailed example

Answer (score 1):

It works in a bit different way:

- Alice uses her secret (private) key to sign a document, and Bob's public key to encrypt a document.
- Bob uses his secret (private) key to decrypt document, and then Alice's public key to verify signature.